# Xamarin Android Google+ Api how to get Profile information

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-plus

I'm using Google+ Api and need to get basic Profile Information. I can correctly log in the user.

In the Xamarin Documentation i found the following call:

```
var person = PlusClass.PeopleApi.GetCurrentPerson(_googleApiClient);
```

But this is shown as deprecated. Someone knows how to get Profile information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is well, but I found a better solution after some further research. I use the "new" GoogleSignInApi now. This works if you insert the dll `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth`.

It's possible to get the user within the `OnActivityResultMethod()` with this line:

```
var signInInfo = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInResultFromIntent(data);
```

Further information: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

Comment: Yes. The signinapi can return the same info, I assumed you were using the Plus API as you were needing the the social aspects of Plus (friends, circles, .... ). If not then yes the signinapi is better.

Answer (score 3):

Use `PlusClass.AccountApi.GetAccountName` to retrieve the user's email.

```
if (client.IsConnected)
{
    var emailAddress = PlusClass.AccountApi.GetAccountName(client);
    Log.Debug(TAG, emailAddress);
}
```

**Note**: You will need `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission to access this data:

Manual Entry via `AndroidManifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Or via Manifest Property Editor:

[image]

## Profile Information:

**Note**: Not all users have all the profile information assigned/available

#### Add `PlusClass.ScopePlusProfile` to your `GoogleApiClient.Builder`:

```
.AddScope(PlusClass.ScopePlusProfile)
```

#### IPerson Example:

```
var emailAddress = PlusClass.AccountApi.GetAccountName(client);
Log.Debug(TAG, emailAddress);
var peopleResult = await PlusClass.PeopleApi.LoadAsync(client, new string[] { "me" } );
if (peopleResult.Status.StatusCode == CommonStatusCodes.Success)
{
    if (peopleResult.PersonBuffer.Count > 0)
    {
        try // try/catch is needed as emumerator will always(?) fault in move next, broken api
        {
            foreach (var person in peopleResult.PersonBuffer)
            {
                Log.Debug(TAG, person.DisplayName);
                Log.Debug(TAG, person.Id);
                Log.Debug(TAG, person.Url);
                if (person.HasImage)
                    Log.Debug(TAG, person.Image.Url);
                Log.Debug(TAG, person.AboutMe);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, $"{e.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            peopleResult.Release(); // prevent memory leak
        }
    }
}
else
{
    Log.Debug(TAG, $"{peopleResult.Status.StatusMessage}");
}
```

#### Sample Output:

```
[MyGPlus] xxxxxx@gmail.com
[MyGPlus] 00000000000000000000
[MyGPlus] Sushi Hangover
[MyGPlus] https://plus.google.com/105138306217936737331
[MyGPlus] https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-F3PtIL2g-dM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAVw/BlrXmOgCSoY/photo.jpg?sz=50
```

Comment: This works fine for getting the E-Mail. Is there a way to get Profilimage, DisplayName and TokenId as well?

Comment: @Sebi I added the getting the user's profile info from GPlus, I think that will get you everything that you are looking for....